# SVG logo disappearing and appearing [vuejs 3 + Laravel 10]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm studying CRUD(vuejs 3 + laravel 9).

I can see the SVG.logo everytime at registration page and login page.
However In CRUD pages those Laravel + vuejs3 + axios combination page's SVG logo showing first, but keep using the page it disappear sudden.

```
  <a href="#" class="flex items-center">
       <img src="logo.svg" alt="logo" class="h-20 mr-1" />  
  </a>
```

When this happens, I did [npm run dev] then temporary fixed.

I tried

> php artisan storage:link

but nothing changed.

Could someone teach me solution please?